# AJAX is posting to different PHP pages at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page user.php which is a template for different users pages (e.g. user.php?id=5). I run an AJAX script to monitor the database for new messages posted during a conversation with each user.

My problem is that when I post a message to user.php?id=5 it also appears on user.php?id=1 etc.

How do I ensure the real-time message is only sent to the correct user?

Script in user.php:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'another_file.php',
        data: { 'action': '<?php echo $lastID; ?>' },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            var avatar = '<img src="images/avatars/' + data[1].avatar + '"/>';
            if (compare_id != data[0].cr_id) {
                $('#responses').prepend("<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-12'><div class='post_container_left_small' style='float:left;'><div class='reply_avatar'><div id='add_button_small'>" + avatar + "</div></div><div class='reply_text'><h3><span class='post_time'>now</h3>" + data[0].reply + "</div></div></div></div>");
            }
            compare_id = data[0].cr_id;
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
}, 7500);
```

The php class function it calls:

```
    public static function getLast($lastID) {

    $lastID = (int)$lastID;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mc_conversation_reply ORDER BY cr_id DESC LIMIT 1");

    $userC = new UserTools();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //echo json_encode($row);

        $userRObj = $userC->get($row['user_id_fk']);

        //echo json_encode($userRObj);
        echo json_encode(array($row,$userRObj));

    }

}
```

Comment: This would depend on how you are fetching your data in the PHP page. You haven't shown this code, so we can't really help. I would assume you need to add a WHERE clause on your query which restricts the result set to the id of the required user.

Comment: You've added the JS, we need to see the PHP.

Comment: Added the PHP class function that it calls, do you need more?

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea is that the user.php is a common "view" (of the [mvc model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) for users on your app and that by using query parameters you must fetch information for just that user. You have chosen to use AJAX (wich is js and runs only under the view layer of your app, in this case, the user's browser) and therefore you need to have some js code listening to some action in order to have two things done: Have php controller layer update the query parameter id and after that run the ajax request again to fetch the database data and update the html fields.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, in this case what is the query parameter id ?

Comment: This `?id=5` bit of the url. Anything after the question mark is called [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string/) or url parameter and I kinda mixed the terms, sorry for that.